# PowerShell Script in Task Scheduler with Async Function

Tags: powershell, function, asynchronous, windows-task-scheduler

I have a fairly large PowerShell script that I've broken into two separate scripts. The first script ends with a call to an async function and then exits.

The function checks on the status of an e-mail export that was generated in the previous script, performing a WHILE loop where it makes a call to Google every sixty seconds to see if the export is ready. Once the export is ready it updates a couple of SQL dbs and my second script knows to take over.

This works 100% of the time when I run the "first script" in the shell/console. But I've started noticing that when my scheduled task is triggered in Task Scheduler that... nothing happens. I have extensive logging, so I know that the parameters ARE being sent over to the async function, but it seems to just poop out rather than continue to loop through the WHILE and do the every-sixty-second checks.

I feel like I've done my due diligence in Googling here, but... is there something I'm missing with a Task Scheduler job to ensure that a function containing a WHILE loop will properly run?

***EDIT BELOW***

To better explain what I'm doing I will include stripped code from my function and the call to the function from the main script below.

First, the call to the function at the very end of "script_01."

```
# Let's send the Google Vault export information over to our function.
        Try {
            $VaultParameters = @{
                employee_name = "$employee_name"
                export_name = "$export_name"
                sql_id = "$sql_id"
                vault_status_id = "$vault_status_id"
            }
            VaultExport @VaultParameters

            $LoggingParameters = @{
                logfile = "C:\script_logs\log.log"
                log = "INFO: Sent the Google Vault export information over to our async function."
            }
            EventLogging @LoggingParameters
        } Catch {
            $LoggingParameters = @{
                logfile = "C:\script_logs\log.log"
                log = "ERROR: Could not send the Google Vault export information over to our async function.`n$_"
            }
            EventLogging @LoggingParameters
        }
```

And now the function itself. It is large...

```
function VaultExport {
    param (
        [cmdletbinding()]
        [parameter()]
        [string]$employee_name,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$export_name,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$sql_id,
        [parameter()]
        [string]$vault_status_id
    )

    $scriptBlock = {
        param ($employee_name,$export_name,$sql_id,$vault_status_id)
        Import-Module SimplySQL
        $logfile = "C:\script_logs\log.log"
        $now = (Get-Date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

        # Let's define our MySQL database credentials for later use.
        # DEFINING SQL CREDS HERE

        # Let's generate secure credentials for our MySQL 'terms' db.
        # GENERATING SECURE CREDS HERE

        # And now we'll connect to our SQL db...
        # CONNECTING TO SQL HERE

        $vault_ready = "no"
        Add-Content $logfile "$now INFO: Beginning the WHILE loop while $export_name completes..."
        while ($vault_ready -eq "no") {
            $vault_status = gam info export "Email Exports" "$export_name"
            $vault_status = $vault_status -Match "COMPLETED"
            $vault_status = $vault_status -split(": ")
            $vault_status = $vault_status[1]
            if ($vault_status -eq "COMPLETED") {
                $vault_ready = "yes"
                $completed = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                Invoke-SqlUpdate -Query "UPDATE ``table`` SET ``vault_status`` = '$vault_status', ``vault_completed`` = '$completed' WHERE ``id`` = '$vault_status_id'"
                Invoke-SqlUpdate -Query "UPDATE ``table`` SET ``vault_status`` = '1' WHERE ``id`` = '$sql_id'"
                $now = (Get-Date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
                Add-Content $logfile "$now INFO: $export_name is ready to download. Updated vault_status in our dbs."
            } else {
                $vault_status = gam info export "Email Exports" "$export_name"
                $vault_status = $vault_status -Match "IN_PROGRESS"
                $vault_status = $vault_status -split(": ")
                $vault_status = $vault_status[1]
                Invoke-SqlUpdate -Query "UPDATE ``table`` SET ``vault_status`` = '$vault_status' WHERE ``id`` = '$vault_status_id'"
                $now = (Get-Date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
                Add-Content $logfile "$now INFO: $export_name is not yet ready: ($vault_status). Checking again in sixty seconds."
                Start-Sleep 60
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($employee_name,$export_name,$sql_id,$vault_status_id)
}
exit
```

Comment: Does it work if you call your script from cmd ? If you run it from an existing Powershell session, which I assume you do when you say the shell / console, then the session will remain open and the async process will continue. From the task scheduler, your async call is done but since it is on another thread, you need to keep the main thread open (eg: While / Start-Sleep -miliseconds 10 until the async function complete). If you don't, the main thread will exit and kill the child threads and the async function while its running. At least, this is the feeling I get from your post.

Comment: Okay. Super helpful... and kind of what my "bad at explaining" brain was thinking. So I need to find out how to keep the main thread / shell open when Task Scheduler triggers my script...

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer not an edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why you wouldn't just have the task execute every 30 seconds instead of having a process run indefinitely and using it's own timers

The condition you are setting for the WHILE statement is being met, this is why the loop doesn't continue.
Change the condition to something that will never be met and the problem should go away, i.e.

```
$Value1 = 0
WHILE($Value1 -ne 1){
#do things, never updating the $value1 variable
}
```

Comment: Here is an abridged version of what I am doing in my async function.

`$vault_ready = "no"
while ($vault_ready -eq "no") {
    # perform the steps to check the current status of the Gmail export
    if ($status = "COMPLETE") {
        # update my SQL tables
        $vault_ready = "yes"
    } else {
        # move along
        start-sleep 60
    }
}`

Comment: @DerekRitchison i'm unable to reproduce the issue. How have you defined the scheduled tasks actions? Is it possible that the script is running in a constrained language mode and as a result is throwing an exception and stopping? Have you set the task to run whether or not the designated user is logged in or not? clicked the tickbox to run with highest permissions?

Comment: Hey there- Thank you for the follow up. To make things a little easier I have edited the original post with sanitized versions of my code --- including the main script where I call my function, and the function itself.

As far as your Qs: It is set to run whether my admin account is logged in or not and I have chosen the highest permissions, yes.

Comment: @DerekRitchison I recommend putting some more logging on the function VaultExport to track exactly where it's being held up.
You have the TRY and CATCH statements above the function call, which means that if anything in the function throws an exception PS will move to the catch statement (i.e. the invoke-sqlupdate function call, from the lack of cred object I assume this is using SSPI which could be failing)

Comment: I know that the Invoke-SqlUpdate commands work when I run the main script (the script that calls this function) in cmd. It is only via Task Scheduler that everything poops out. I'm assuming this is because of what Saga Pourpre mentioned: "From the Task Scheduler, your async call is done but since it is on another thread, you need to keep the main thread open,"

So I need to come up with a way to keep the main thread running even though Task Scheduler tends to close the PowerShell instance as soon as the main script is done.

Comment: I'm happy to close out this request if there are no more suggestions. I'm personally at a loss and not sure how to "keep the thread open" when the script is triggered via Task Scheduler.

Comment: @DerekRitchison I'm not convinced that's the issue here. If that was the case, one would theoretically be able to reproduce the issue with alternative code (which I cannot). I would recommend adding transcription functionality to the async script, this way you can actually identify if it's throwing an exception or if the threaded process is being terminated prematurely.

Comment: I think the threaded process would have to be terminated prematurely here. When I run the exact same script via PowerShell, not via Task Scheduler, it calls the function and everything runs as expected with an every-sixty-second WHILE loop and db updates until the export is ready, at which point it passes the baton to my second script.

Comment: Good luck in your investigation then, I'm not confident that's the issue

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and the back-and-forth, but I'm genuinely curious why it would not be related to Task Scheduler / the Task Scheduler instance of triggering the script if the same script does everything as expected when I run it manually, outside of Task Scheduler. If there is something obvious I'm missing I am all ears, but I am currently comparing the exact same script in two scenarios: 1) being run manually via a PowerShell instance, and 2) being run on a set schedule via a task in Task Scheduler.

Comment: The issue likely is not with the script itself but how it is executed.
There are a variety of configurables for task scheduler which may affect, incl (but not limited to): Acc. Running the task (does it have permissions? can it run a non-constrained language mode?), Run whether user is logged on or not (do any functions require desktop access? this can cause exceptions), Run with highest privs (get around any UAC issues).
There are also a bunch of things that could stop the task, 'stop if switches to battery power' found in conditions tab. in Settings also, 'stop the task if it runs xxx'

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the "fix" was to add "-NoExit" to the argument list in the Task Scheduler action.

---

Ultimately what I learned was that a Start-Job is going to die as soon as the "shell" is closed, and the shell will always close when the script/task ends in Task Scheduler.

The -NoExit flag did "fix" this, but I very quickly learned that it prevented any future task from running since the first task still hadn't exited. This task runs once a minute, for all of eternity, so -NoExit broke my automations pretty quickly.

I ended up rewriting the entire flow so I am no longer using an async function but three separate scripts that know when to run based on SQL updates that I am making at the beginning and end of each said script.

How exactly this had been working before (and it was, for years) is still beyond me. I feel like I had some very specific flags in my Task Scheduler "Action" that kept the shell open until the Start-Job was confirmed done. Not really sure, this ain't my forte...